# Earth Clock widget for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

Is there an Earth Clock widget for Windows 7's desktop?

I mean something like this, a view of the earth, with the evolution of the light part, according to the time (the clocks in themselves are not really important):

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Do you mean something which mostly would provide the earth image, updated with the current sun position? Or simply the different clocks, from different areas?

Comment: Mostly the map with the sun. Not the clocks.

Comment: someone voted to close this as "too localized"??  this is practically the complete opposite!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a gadget that provides the map and not the clock:

[Sun Clock Vista Gadget](http://www.incidentmap.co.uk/shadowfacts/v65/gadget.htm)

[image]

[WorldTimeServer.com](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/clocks/) has a couple of sidebar gadgets provide world clocks.  You can create a separate instance for each timezone you want to track.

[image: 12-hour clocks] [image: 24-hour clocks]

Answer (score 1):

I think this could suit your needs: [Sun Clock](http://sarahs-muse.livejournal.com/934372.html).

[image: sun clock]

This is a conversion of a Yahoo! widget for Windows 7, made recently. It is still a work in progress, and obviously you can post comment on the given page, the author is open to suggestions.

[Direct link to the widget](http://untamed.co.uk/gadgets/SunClock.gadget).